# Find a primitive root of $17^{1974}$. How many primitive roots of $17^{1974}$ are there?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find a primitive root of $17^{1974}$.  How many primitive roots of $17^{1974}$ are there?

I found that $3$ is a primitive root of $17$ so I have to check whether or not $3^{16} \not \equiv 1 \pmod{17^2}$ then $3$ is a primitive root of $17^2$ and thus $17^{1974}$ or else $3+17$ or $20$ is.

My issue is I don't see how to easily compute $3^{16} \not \equiv 1 \pmod{17^2}$ by hand.

Comment: Just go slowly.  $3^8=81^2\equiv ?\pmod {17^2}$?  Once you have that, just square again.

Comment: Calculate $((((3^2)^2)^2)^2)$, reducing modulo $17^2$ as you go along.

Comment: Write $81=(85-4)$

Comment: So, the actual question is different from the title?

Comment: I ended up getting $171$ but the computations were long with the division. I wasn't sure if there was a simple trick to make it easier. So once I have that  $3$ is a primiritive root would all other primitive roots be of the form $3^i$ where $gcd(i,\phi(17^{1974})=1$ ?

Comment: @HighSchool15 That's correct. By definition, 3 will generate every number, including the other $\phi(\phi(17^{1974}))$ primitive roots which are primitive if i is relatively prime to $\phi(17^{1974})$